# How to fix "Sub or Function not defined" when using HSL Function

Tags: excel, vba, colors, rgb, hsl

I'm trying to set the interior color of some cells using HSL instead of RGB.

Judging by this documentation from Microsoft, it's very simple:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/hsl-function

The syntax is simply HSL(** hue **, ** saturation **, ** luminosity ** )

Why, then, is my VBA telling me the sub or function is not defined?

The same error occurs for both of these lines of code:

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = HSL(160, 240, 120)

Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = HSL(160, 240, 120)
```

Comment: That's Visio, not Excel.

Comment: [This](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/861949-hsl-rgb.html) might possibly be useful.

Comment: Use the [RGB function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) instead. HSL does not exist in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative method for converting between RGB → HSL in VBA, using a Windows API.  Since it's a "Classic Windows" function it has a couple idiosyncrasies.

### RGB to HSL with `ColorRGBToHLS`

> [`ColorRGBToHLS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-colorrgbtohls) is an Windows API function which therefore uses an outdated color range that's been carried forward since the 1980's (originally used in a long-defunct program called *MS Chart*).  You may be familiar with converting R/G/B values between percentages and values out of `255`.
>
> - However in this case the conversion must be to/from [values out of **`240`**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151013-00/?p=91371), not 255.
> - Just to further confuse us here in the future, they used notation of `HLS` instead of more-common `HSL` (and hex color strings are `0xBBGGRR` instead of `#RRGGBB`).

tl;dr

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub ColorRGBToHLS Lib "shlwapi.dll" (ByVal clrRGB As Long, _
    wHue As Integer, wLuminance As Integer, wSaturation As Integer)

Function rgb_to_hsl(r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer)
  Dim h As Integer, s As Integer, l As Integer
  ColorRGBToHLS RGB(r, g, b), h, l, s
  h = 360 * (h / 239)
  s = 100 * (s / 240)
  l = 100 * (l / 240)
  rgb_to_hsl = "hsl(" & h & "," & s & "%," & l & "%)"
End Function
```

...and a [demo](https://rgb.to/255,180,63):

```
Sub test()
  Debug.Print rgb_to_hsl(255, 180, 63)  'returns "hsl(36,100%,62%)"
End Sub
```

By the way the API also has a [`ColorHLSToRGB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-colorhlstorgb) function.

<sub>The 80's was a crazy (often confusing) time for computer nerds.  Fun fact: Bill Gates married the first female programmer he hired.</sub>